# Malloc() memory corruption error after concatenating a string

Tags: c, string, memory-management, strcat

Guys I'm generating a string which rappresent a path to a file, concatenating a macro and a string. The function is this:

```
char *userPath(char *username)
{
   char *path = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(MAILBOXES) + strlen(username) + 1));
   path[0] = '\0';
   strcat(path, MAILBOXES);
   strcat(path, "/");
   strcat(path, username);
   return path;
}
```

The returned pointer reference a correct string, but after some call to this function the process throws out a very very bad *** glibc detected**  ./mmboxd: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x085310a8 ** with the relative backtrace. I know it's here the problem, since I started having this error once implemented it, and also because the only malloc I use is here. What's wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: Casting `malloc` isn't necessary, and `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so you can simplify the `malloc` call to `char *path = malloc(STRLEN(MAILBOXES) + strlen(username) + 2);`

Comment: @John Bode - Some people (not myself necessarily) say that you should use `char *path = malloc(sizeof *path * whatever);` so that if you change the type of `path` (to, say, `wchar_t *`) the `malloc` will adjust the size accordingly.

Comment: Writing `sizeof *path` is arguably reasonable, but `sizeof(char)` is definitely not.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: actually, that's my normal paradigm, but I figured I'd keep this as simple as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The +1 should be +2 to take into account the separator you add and the null terminator. And you can omit sizeof(char), which will always be 1.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the problem:

```
   char *path = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(MAILBOXES) + strlen(username) + 1));
```

You're allocating enough memory for a) all the characters in `MAILBOXES`, b) all the characters in `username`, and c) the `'/'` character, but you're forgetting d) the terminating `'\0'` character! So `+ 1` should be `+ 2`

There are a few other oddities about your code, but they're not wrong, just things that could be better:

1. You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C, and some (like me) consider it bad style for various reasons that you're more than capable of Googling.
2. `sizeof(char)` is always 1 (this is defined in the standard). Some people say to keep it in for symmetry. Some say take it out since it's one. Some say change it to `sizeof *path`, so that if you change `path` to a `wchar_t *` the `malloc` will correctly adjust to keep allocating the right size.
3. Using `strcat` to write the first bit of data to a string is potentially inefficient. Why not drop the `path[0] = '\0';` line and just use `strcpy` for the first bit of data?
4. You calculate the lengths of all of the strings, but then you throw them away and use `strcat`, which will re-traverse the (previously calculated) lengths to find the right spot. If you stored the results of your two `strlen` calls, you wouldn't need to use `strcat` and unnecessarily keep recalculating where the end of the string is.
5. Using `strcat` to append a single character is inefficient.
6. You don't check the return value of `malloc` for success or failure before you use it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm googling to better undestand wyh is a god pratice to not cast the malloc and I'll use strcpy for the first byte

Comment: Better not to use `strcpy` and `strcat` at all. Instead use `snprintf(path, len, MAILBOXES "/%s", username);` where `len` is the same as the argument you passed to `malloc`. This way there is no danger of overflow.

Comment: @R.. - If the `malloc` didn't fail (which is something else I forgot to mention) there's no danger of overflow either way, once the OP corrects the off-by-one error.

Comment: I mean if OP had done it with `snprintf` then the question would have been "why is the last character being truncated?" rather than "why do I have memory corruption?" and OP probably would have figured it out without even having to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to have allowed space for the zero-terminator.  You should be allocating an extra `char` for that.

I'm assuming that the `+1` in the `malloc()` is for the path separator.  Make it `+2` and you'll have space for the terminating null character.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate the "path" string you forgot to add the length of the "/" char that you add between MAILBOXES and username.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you would need to malloc an another byte for zero termination.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate one extra byte for null character "\x00" as the string terminator in C strings.

Currently you allocate only one extra byte for / character.

So try +2 instead of +1

Answer (score 1):

You're not budgeting in a char for the terminating null.  Your malloc length should be +2, not +1.

Answer (score 1):

Your `+1` in the end of `malloc()` accounts for the `/`. But you need space for the null character at the end, which is added by `strcat()`. So it's a `+2`.

```
char *path = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(MAILBOXES) + strlen(username) + 2));
```

Comment: Be sure to format your code as code (I fixed it) or `*`'s will disappear and change to italics. Also you can do away with the cast.